# Using chart as a chart and not as a link in using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

The following code copies data from excel and pastes it into Power Point as 
 an object but what if I want to paste chart as a chart with data embedded in it.

```
Sub chart_to_Xcl()

    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppt.Visible = msoCTrue

    Dim ppres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set ppres = ppt.Presentations.Add


    Dim pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide   
    Set pSlide = ppres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim j As Long
    j = 0

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select


        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            j = j + 1
        Next 
        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            myChart.Select
            myChart.Copy
            pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial link:=msoCTrue

            Set pSlide = ppres.Slides.Add(ppres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly) 

        Next

    Next

End Sub

Sub chart_to_Xcl()

    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppt.Visible = msoCTrue

    Dim ppres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set ppres = ppt.Presentations.Add


    Dim pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Set pSlide = ppres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim j As Long
    j = 0

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select


        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            j = j + 1
        Next
        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            myChart.Select
            myChart.Copy
            pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial link:=msoCTrue

            Set pSlide = ppres.Slides.Add(ppres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

        Next

    Next


End Sub


Sub chart_to_Xcl()

    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppt.Visible = msoCTrue

    Dim ppres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set ppres = ppt.Presentations.Add


    Dim pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Set pSlide = ppres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim j As Long
    j = 0

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select


        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            j = j + 1
        Next
        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            myChart.Select
            myChart.Copy
            pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial link:=msoCTrue

            Set pSlide = ppres.Slides.Add(ppres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

        Next

    Next

End Sub


Sub chart_to_Xcl()

    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppt.Visible = msoCTrue

    Dim ppres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set ppres = ppt.Presentations.Add


    Dim pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Set pSlide = ppres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim j As Long
    j = 0

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select


        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            j = j + 1
        Next
        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            myChart.Select
            myChart.Copy
            pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial link:=msoCTrue

            Set pSlide = ppres.Slides.Add(ppres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

        Next

    Next


End Sub
```

So let's say I want to use filter on some column in the powerpoint itself, for example,  I want to see the records only for year 2017 by using filter in my slide but with this code I am not able to see the filter or style option in power point.

Comment: Share what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Sam I have pasted the code that I have created so far